# Тулза для конвертирования layout xml в Java код

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Может кто встречал какую утилитку? Когда есть xml с layout-ом, а хочется получить код, который в рантайме [генерит](http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2924/14541430241_cb4d73f753_o.png) такой же layout.

Comment: Интересный вопрос...    
Мне самому оно не нужно, но если такого еще не сделали, я бы взялся написать...

Comment: Не так давно видел парочку соответствующих плагинов в стандартных репозиториях IntelliJ IDEA. В виде standalone утилиты — не видел, впрочем, и не искал. А вообще, не могу представить, кому и зачем это может понадобиться. Не поделитесь use-case'ом?

Comment: @falstaf, смотрите. Нужен нам какой-нибудь кастомный view (внутри него будут TextView, Button...), всю обработку-логику я прячу внутри его view, наружу только свойства. Можно внутри нашего кастома делать inflate от layout, этот layout лежит в ресурсах. Но, во-первых, не всегда хочется, чтобы такие второстепенные контролы захламляли res\layout.
А, во-вторых, по хорошему в этом layout надо корневой view делать <merge>, т.к. если задать просто LinearLayout, и наш кастомный view будет тоже наследоваться от LinearLayout, то получаем один контейнер лишний.

Comment: @falstaf, ...но тогда теряется вообще смысл от xml, т.к. визуально там будут все views в куче. Отсюда выход - раз не так, то ладно, возьмём тестовый проект, там кладём наш xml layout c корневым LinearLayout, он хорошо смотрится, его легко редактировать. Берём утилиту, проходим, получаем код, вставляем его в ctor и я доволен :-)

Comment: @Schumi, не понимаю. Чем же понятный и удобный для редактирования xml layout хуже, чем автоматически сгенерированный многострочный код, делающий то же самое, но который тяжело читать, понимать, сопровождать и ещё тяжелее редактировать? Окей, предположим, понадобилось потом этот кастомный view изменить. В случае с layout'ом всё просто. Что же делать в вашем случае?

Comment: @Schumi: А что мешает руками написать? Там же делать нечего, работы на 2 дня, с перерывами на кофе и чат.

@falstaf: я вижу пока только одно применение: допустим, что UI надо генерировать на лету в зависимости от runtime-данных. Тогда сгенерированный код можно взять за основу при разработке runtime-генерации.

Comment: ожидаю вопроса "как код, который создает layout превратить в xml"!

Comment: @KoVadim: 1) запустить код, 2) сериализовать сгенерированное визуальное дерево в XML :-/

Comment: @falstaf, так в том то и дело, что не будет он понятным (я про <merge>). Для меня useless контейнер критично.
@VladD, вполне логично прежде, чем изобретать велосипед, узнать/спросить о уже существующих велосипедах.

Comment: @Schumi, почему это `<merge>` сделает вдруг layout непонятным? Та же IntelliJ IDEA вполне умеет правильно рендерить layout с `merge` в зависимости от типа view, который его инфлэйтит, и назначенного в `tools:context`. Который, в общем-то, для этих целей и предназначен.

----

Как выяснилось, для этого есть ещё и `tools:showIn`.

Comment: @metalurgus давай напишем :)

Comment: @falstaf, погоди, наверно, я не правильно объяснил. У меня есть MyView (extends LinearLayout), есть в mylayout.xml (корень у него <merge>). В ctor я делаю inflate() этого layout. В результате в Эклипсе у меня в дизайне каша.
Смотри, насчёт tools:context и tools:showIn. В первом параметре надо указывать активити, чтобы в дизайнере подхватывалась тема из манифеста. Второй недоступен в Эклипсе. Но суть не в этом, там надо указывать layout. Но его у меня нет, есть MyView.

Comment: @falstaf, можно, конечно, создать фейковый layout, внутри которого будет один LinearLayout. Но это не серьезно, учитывая, что для разных контролов у меня могут использоваться разные рут контейнеры с разными параметрами.
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes

Comment: @VladD

запустить, сериализировать... не все так просто. А кто будет вместо текста подставлять строковые ресурсы. А код ещё на разных девайсах нужно позапускать (хотя запустить  -это опасно, мало чего он там сделает:) ).

Comment: @KoVadim: не, подстановку ресурсов надёжно не зареверсить никак. Текст может вполне быть создан в коде и не опираясь на ресурсы.

Answer (score 1):

> А, во-вторых, по хорошему в этом layout надо корневой view делать <merge>, т.к. если задать просто LinearLayout, и наш кастомный view будет тоже наследоваться от LinearLayout, то получаем один контейнер лишний.

Вы не правы, можно сделать и без лишнего вложения.  Есть прекрасные приемы. Принцип похож на ViewHolder.

Берем разметку xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >
      <!--icon-->
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"            
            android:layout_weight="0"
            />
    <!--names-->
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"                                            
                />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

И создаем класс, который будет выполнять роль конструктора

```
public class MyCustomHolder
{
    private final View mainContent;

    private final ImageView icon;
    private final TextView textView;
    private final TextView textView2;   
    private CustomObject object;
    private final Context mContext;

    public MyCustomHolder(final Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mainContent = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

        icon = ((ImageView) mainContent.findViewById(R.id.icon));
        textView = (TextView) mainContent.findViewById(R.id.name1);
        textView2 = (TextView) mainContent.findViewById(R.id.name2);
        mainContent.setTag(this);
    }

    public void setObject(final CustomObject object)
    {
        this.object = object;        
        textView.setText(object.getName());
        textView2.setText(object.getSubtitle());
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

    }

    public View getView()
    {
        return mainContent;
    }

    public CustomObject getObject()
    {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Использовать становится совсем просто.

```
MyCustomHolder holder = new MyCustomHolder(context);
holder.setObject(myObject); //наполняем данными
View myView = holder.getView();//получаем нужный View

((MyCustomHolder)myView.getTag())//достаем holder для изменения View
```

Такой прием гораздо удобней, нежели сгенерить огромное полотно кода. К тому же, не все можно сделать легко в коде, что позволяет разметка в xml.

Comment: > не все можно сделать в коде, что позволяет разметка в xml

Например?

Comment: @falstaf, наверно имелось в виду "не все можно *легко* сделать в коде".

Comment: @SuperCreeper да, именно так. исправил